# How can I use wheredate and wherehas simultaneously?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query is like this :

```
$search = $request->get('search');
$search_date = $request->get('search_date');
$store = Store::whereDate('updated_at', $search_date)->orWhereHas('user'), function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where(function ($q) use($search)
    {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%',$search.'%');
    });
})->paginate(10);
```

When executed, there is no error. But the result not match with the filter date

When I only use wheredate without wherehas, it's match with the filter

What the `wheredate` and `wherehas` is not can run simultaneously?

**Update**

I have 2 input text, that is input text for datepicker and input text to search name. When the user wants to do searching, he can input updated date and input name. Then click the search button. And the system will filter it out.

Comment: First of all you're missing a > before paginate and a ; at the end of the second row

Comment: If you need `and` conjunctions, don't use `or`.

Comment: @CalinBlaga Thx, fixed.

Comment: I had update my question

Answer (score 0):

You used `orWhereHas`. If you want both tour criteria (wheredate AND wherehas), you should use `wherehas` instead of `orWhereHas`:

```
$store = Store::whereDate('updated_at', $search_date)->whereHas('user'), function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where(function ($q) use($search) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%',$search.'%');
    });
})->paginate(10);
```

In other words, if you need both condition to be true, use `and`, not `or` (`and` is implicit with laravel query builder)

Comment: I have two input text to search. First. input text to datepicker, Second, input text to input data. User can input to filter it

Comment: I don't see the point with your question: "How can I use wheredate and wherehas simultaneously?". I'm lost sorry. I thought I understood what you want, but I'm not sure with your last comment...

Comment: What do you mean? I'm still confused

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630043/why-wheredate-not-working-in-laravel-5-3. Maybe you can help me